# Is it possible to run ionic cordova on specified IP host and port

Tags: ionic-framework, port, host, ionic5, listen

I run the following command to run ionic app on a particular host and port:

```
ionic cordova run browser --host=139.180.15.147 --port=8200
```

The process starts, however, the log says it is running on localhost. See below output:

```
Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
```

I then tried doing this.

```
  export IONIC_CMDOPTS_CORDOVA_RUN_LIVERELOAD_PORT=8200
  export IONIC_CMDOPTS_CORDOVA_RUN_HOST=139.180.15.147
  ionic cordova run browser --host=139.180.15.147 --port=8200
```

But still no luck.

I have made sure there is no firewall blocking the IP and port.

I'm unable to telnet from my local system as below:

```
telnet 139.180.15.147 8200
Connecting To 139.180.15.147...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8200: Connect failed
```

It works and we are able to telnet from our local systems when we try the below ionic command without `cordova`

```
ionic serve --host 139.180.15.147 -p 8200 &
```

We are on the latest versions of all the products as this is a new setup.

```
# ionic --version
6.10.1
```

However, my project was built on a different system having `ionic5`

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: In ionic capacitor you add server and ip inside capacitor.config.json but in cordova i think and not sure its from config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ionic serve --host=0.0.0.0 --public-host=<hostname>
```